# How to get Medium to display visualization instead of code block for HTML

Tags: html, github, medium.com-publishing-api

I'm working on adding an interactive plot in a Medium post.
Plot was created in Altair (I have another one in BERTopic I'm also trying to add), and is saved as `.html`.

On my computer, the `.html` opens in Chrome and has the features I want.

I've tried a variety of ways to embed it.
I keep ending up with raw HTML code on the page instead of the interactive plot.

My most recent attempt resulted in putting it in a public gist on GitHub, and it still just shares the code but no visualization.
I've tried both with the script option and with just the link, using embed and code options.

When I search, I keep coming across "help" that is about embedding a code snippet, not the visualization itself.

How do I get the visualization to appear instead?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd
# https://towardsdatascience.com/simplest-way-of-creating-a-choropleth-map-by-u-s-states-in-python-f359ada7735e
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, 'states')
url = 'https://gist.github.com/mauvegrrl/40e6279e636b66d0a1f694a850334dc3/raw'
sbl = pd.read_csv(url)
upper_color = round(sbl['count'].max(), -2)

fill = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape().encode(
    tooltip=['state:N','count:Q', 'lists:N'],
    color = alt.Color('count:Q', 
                      scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, upper_color]))
    ).project('albersUsa').properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(sbl, 'id', ['state','lists','count'])
)

fill
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Done. Kept links in code block, tho.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a raw gist, adding `/raw` at the end of the URL is enough.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mauvegrrl/921a6e3e76f7660fca71921f3af2a84e/raw

But yes, that would display the raw HTML code, because the response `content-type` would be `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.
This is what you see in "[Adding GitHub Codes in Medium Articles](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/adding-github-codes-in-medium-articles-ff3c44940bbf)"

I suspect a GitHub pages might not be easily embedded in Medium.
But a [Jupyter Notebook can](https://ai.plainenglish.io/how-to-embed-code-or-jupyter-notebook-in-medium-7464411217e7): if you can make your [Altair graph in a Jupyter Notebook](https://vitalflux.com/altair-python-install-jupyter-notebook/), that would be a good workaround.

Comment: I saved a barebones df necessary for the plot to a public gist, reduced the code to just what's necessary to pull the data, and put that on a public gist. I'm still just getting code, and if there's a way to run it, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @mauve You need to include your Altair plot in a Jupyter Notebook, [as explained here](https://vitalflux.com/altair-python-install-jupyter-notebook/), then include that Notebook in your Medium article, as [explained here](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/adding-github-codes-in-medium-articles-ff3c44940bbf).

Comment: I did exactly that, and it just shows the code and if it's runnable I cannot figure out how. https://gist.github.com/mauvegrrl/0fd727891324b3640369704ace1b1c5d

Comment: @mauve, But your gist does not represent a Jupyter Notebook, as the one  illustrated in "[Hello World – Altair Python Install in Jupyter Notebook](https://vitalflux.com/altair-python-install-jupyter-notebook/)".

Comment: And how would I change that? It's an .ipynb file, I wrote it in colab, this post doesn't explain the "how to make it a Jupyter Notebook" part.

Comment: @mauve The post suggest to use `pip install altair vega_datasets` and [start the Notebook server](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html). From there, you can re-implement your script there.